# ionic app resume and pause

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, background-process, resume

I want my app to do something when it comes form it's background state to the active state. I understand according the cordova documentation I can do this with the code below and this is working.

```
// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
   document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

// Handle the resume event
//
   function onResume() {
}
```

My app is build with Ionic and the downside of using the code above is that it only work outside my app module, so I can't trigger functions inside my app module. I found a few code example on how it should work inside my app module, but non of them are working. See some examples below.

```
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
    // rock on
});
```

/

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
    ionic.on('resume', function(){
        //rock on
    }, element);
});
```

/

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceReady", function () {
            document.addEventListener("resume", function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    //rock on
                }, 0);
            }, false);
        });
    });
```

Am I doing something wrong am I forgetting something, I hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

For the ionic you try the following code, hopes it helps to you

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
       //code for action on pause
      }, false);
      document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
       //code for action on resume
      }, false);
});
```

Comment: any insight as to why "resume" listener doesn't get called when clicking phone number on iOS?

Comment: ionic app resume and pause, I need solution for ionic 4

Answer (score 6):

We can use the $ionicPlatform to listen the resume event of an ionic application. This event fires once the application resumes.

```
$ionicPlatform.on("resume", function (event) {
    // will execute when device resume.
});
```

Have a look at [CodeExpertz](http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/mobile/identifying-app-resume-event-ionic-android) for example